# How to adust margin in listoftheorem

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems

I have some definitions and theorems inside subsubsubsection. When latex generates the listoftheorems, the last digit of the subsubsubsection overlaps the first letter of the name of the theorem, definition, etc. How could I adjust the space between the number of the definitions and its label when I am generating the list of theorems using \listoftheorem of the package thmtools

Thanks,

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\declaretheoremstyle[
            spaceabove=6pt, 
            spacebelow=6pt,
            headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
            notefont=\mdseries,            %da ainda para incluir outros argumentos, como \color{red}, 
            notebraces={(}{)},
            bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
            postheadspace=\newline,
            numberwithin=subsubsection,
            shaded={rulecolor=black,
                        rulewidth=.4pt, 
                        bgcolor=grey!20}]{defStyle}
\declaretheorem[name=Definition,style=defStyle]{definition}
%=================================================

\begin{document}
\listoftheorems


\section{First}
    \subsection{First}
      \subsubsection{First}
      \end{subsection}
      \subsubsection{Second}
                \begin{definition}[name]
                 adslkjafhsldfkh asdfhkh adfadsfa $f(x)$
                \end{definition}
        \end{subsection}
        \end{subsection}
  \end{subsubsection}

\end{section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you doing? `\end{subsection}` etc. are no valid commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The width reserved to typeset the sectional unit number is controlled by  `\thmt@listnumwidth`, with a default value of `2.3em`. You can increase this value according to your needs (I used `3.5em` in my example below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\declaretheoremstyle[
            spaceabove=6pt, 
            spacebelow=6pt,
            headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
            notefont=\mdseries, 
            notebraces={(}{)},
            bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
            postheadspace=\newline,
            numberwithin=subsubsection,
            shaded={rulecolor=black,
                        rulewidth=.4pt, 
                        bgcolor=gray!20}]{defStyle}
\declaretheorem[name=Definition,style=defStyle]{definition}
%=================================================

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thmt@listnumwidth{3.5em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoftheorems


\section{First}
\subsection{First}
\subsubsection{First}
\subsubsection{Second}
\begin{definition}[Test]
Test
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, there's no such thing as `\end{section}`, `\end{subsection}`, etc. I delete those from your code (otherwise, one gets errors).