# Lists of Theorems (XeLaTeX)

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems

I've found out how to use the `thmtools` package to make lists of theorems. My questions on this are:

1. Adding `[name=xxx,label=thm:...]` after `\begin{yyy}` (xxx is a title for the theorem, ... a label appearing in the list, yyy the theorem kind) labels a theorem. If I try to put any maths beyond superscript and subscript (for now I've only tried `\mathbb`) into a label, I get a `missing \endcsname inserted` error related to a line of the .aux files. MWE:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{report}  
   \usepackage{thmtools,amssymb}  
   \declaretheorem[name=Definizione]{defi}  
   \begin{document}  
   \begin{defi}[name=$\mathbb R$,label=thm:$\mathbb R$definizione]  
   Ah beh, s\`i beh.  
   \end{defi}  
   \listoftheorems  
   \end{document}
   ```

which gives:
[image: Error message in TeXShop Console].
The same error is obtained by placing a `\ref` in a label. In fact, `\mathbb` gives problems anywhere in those [], just like a comma in the middle of a name or label, even within dollars to mark an interval like (0,1). How do I solve that?

2. (should be 2) And finally, I'm using theorems with `[subsection]` numbering. Now, in the list, the number overlaps the theorem kind (i.e. I get `1.2.1.1` overlapping `Definizione (Spazio Metrico)`). How do I solve that?

Comment: `label=<string>` defines a string to be used for `\ref`; it shouldn't contain any command or special character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value for the key `label` should be a mnemonic string to be used in the argument of `\ref` for referring to this theorem number.

It shouldn't contain any command and any special character (and it will never appear in print). So

```
\begin{defi}[name=$\mathbb{R}$,label=thm:R-definizione]
```

is what you need. When you want to refer to this definition, type

```
\ref{thm:R-definizione}
```

---

Please, note that the correct input is `\mathbb{R}`, not `\mathbb R`. The fact that the latter gives the same result shouldn't be taken as a proof that the input is valid.

Comment: OK. Why does `\mathbb R` give problems and `\mathbb{R}` not give any? And what about point 2?

Comment: @MickG `\mathbb{R}` in `label=` gives the same problem as `\mathbb R`. About point 2, there should be something on the site.

Comment: I meant `\mathbb R` gives problems in `name=` and `\mathbb{R}` doesn't. The error given is in the question.

Comment: @MickG What is suggesting you that the error you got came from `name=\mathbb R`? It didn't. For the margins in the list of theorems, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115265/how-to-adust-margin-in-listoftheorem or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53774/horizontal-spacing-issue-in-listoftheorems-using-amsthm-thmtools

Comment: This IS strange. Maybe it was trying to update the already existing .loe file and found the error in the label with `\mathbb R`, even though I had removed `\mathbb R` from the label. Could that be? Anyway the error is gone now.

Comment: @MickG When you corrected the `label`, the first LaTeX run still had the incorrect one in the `aux` file, whence the error. If you went past it, a new `.aux` file was created, without the erroneous entry.

Comment: The tip in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115265/how-to-adust-margin-in-listoftheorem solves the problem. Just one last question: what are `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` for?

Comment: @MickG http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: Is there a way to put a comma in a `name`?

Comment: @MickG `name={x, y, z}`